# Ubuntu 19.04 and VMPlayer 15

Tags: vmware, 19.04

Every time I install a major Ubuntu version, VMWare Player needs to be recompiled with the new kernel.

```
Virtual machine monitor                        failed
Virtual machine communication interface        done
VM communication interface socket family       done
Blocking file system                           done
Virtual ethernet                               failed
VMware Authentication Daemon                   done
```

Both the Monitor and Ethernet keep with the failed status.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with some VMWare scripts that don't take into account the new Ubuntu version number.

Couldn't get it to work and tried all the workarounds I could find (none of them with Ubuntu 19.04)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Hey there, can you clarify the output of the compilation process?

Comment: Thanks Phillippe, found a workaround on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135669/vmware-player-15-unable-to-start-on-fresh-install-of-19-04 and work straightforward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMWare Player 15 Unable to Start on Fresh Install of 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135669/vmware-player-15-unable-to-start-on-fresh-install-of-19-04)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior for any new kernel release and existing kernel objects / modules will not work until they are updated and made compatible with the kernel you are running.

However in your case, it appears like there is a non-official patch available which I have tried and it worked for me but I do not recommend it hence for not posting the link but if you still want to go ahead with it, please respond to this post and request it.

Comment: Thanks marko for the answer. I am in need of the workaround. My 3d printer's software only works on win. I'm actually stuck with this.

Comment: Used a workaround from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135669/vmware-player-15-unable-to-start-on-fresh-install-of-19-04 and worked straightforward.