# VMWare Player 15 Unable to Start on Fresh Install of 19.04?

Tags: kubuntu, vmware, 19.04

I have a question very similar to ([15.04 VMWare Player "unable to start services" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614525/15-04-vmware-player-unable-to-start-services-error/)) in that the modules cannot be compiled.

However, the top solution does not work for me.
[image: Error]

Here is the terminal commands that I used:

```
root@LesserArk:~# uname -r 
5.0.0-13-generic
root@LesserArk:~# man dkms
root@LesserArk:~# curl https://pastebin.com/raw/Z1ihzbcE -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1646    0  1646    0     0   4485      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4485
root@LesserArk:~# 
root@LesserArk:~# cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
root@LesserArk:/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source# tar -xf vmnet.tar
root@LesserArk:/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source# cd vmnet-only
root@LesserArk:/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet-only# patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -ur vmnet-only.a/driver.c vmnet-only/driver.c
|--- vmnet-only.a/driver.c      2014-11-20 20:13:56.000000000 -0500
|+++ vmnet-only/driver.c        2015-02-09 15:40:10.916640592 -0500
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] y
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
can't find file to patch at input line 45
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! When the top solution doesn't work, check the next one. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well I was having the same issue, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052104/928088) could be a possible solution. The same workaround has also been accepted as the solution in [VMware communities](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/609330). From [Charly's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052104/928088) on [Installing VMware on 18.04: Failed to build vmmon](https://askubuntu.com/q/1041912/928088):

Create a script file based on [mkucebek's github sources](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules), and run it each time it's needed, usually when you install a new kernel:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-15.0.4
TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware
rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER
mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER
cd $TMP_FOLDER
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules
git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION
git fetch
make
sudo make install
sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 
/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Comment: Fixed it for me on KUbuntu 19.04

Comment: Fixed it for me on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: This did not work for me in 19.04 with Workstation 15.5.0. The solution for me was to go into BIOS and disable secure boot.