# VMWare Player Cannot Install VMWare Tools for Linux?

Tags: kubuntu, vmware, 19.04

There are quite a few questions on this,but I think mine is unique.

I get this error when trying to install VMWare Tools on a 18.04 linux machine: [image: VMWare Tools]

I was only able to get VMWare running due to Jag's script (https://askubuntu.com/a/1135683/645874). I'm not sure if this impacted the viability of VMWare Tools.

Is there any fix for this? What should I do to resolve it?